# How does machine-learning deal with multi-dimensional data?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I undertand how the weighting of different inputs and how it's used to calculate the cost, basically this:

[image]

and also how it can be used to do deeper networks, but how would a network deal with something like an rgb-image, where some data is inheritly bundled together?

Comment: A network will usually use **hidden-layers** to learn to combine those features (which are somehow correlated). In this case, the final linear-activation (as seen in your picture) does not act on single.dimensions, but on some (possibly nonlinear) combination of many features/dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we have an image of w * h pixels (w = width, h = height).

The most straightforward way would be to simply create w * h * 3 input nodes; for every pixel, three input nodes (one for R value, one for G value, one for B value). With a large enough dataset for training, it should not be a problem to split up the data in this way.

You're right that you do lose some information initially; there is nothing inherently in the structure of the network that tells it that the first three input nodes are somehow related to each other (same pixel), the three after that as well, etc. Given a suffiently large amount of training data it should (in theory) be able to pick up on such patterns though.

Depending on the problem domain, it may also be beneficial to simply get rid of the color-information. Instead you could convert the image to grayscale, and then you'd only need one input node per pixel. Obviously you lose information this way as well, but for some tasks that information may not be necessary (and getting rid of it can make your training more efficient computationally).